# vi / vim - how to set the tab label/title length to a fixed size in chars

Tags: vim, tabs, vi

As I open new tabs in vi/vim(7.2), if the opened files are in different paths the tab title displays the complete path and hogs the screen real estate so the other tabs are not visible. This means I can't use my mouse to click to the tab I want but have to resort to : & keyboard commands to move between tabs.

Is there any way I can restrict the tab titles to a max 'size/length', so I only get to see say the last 12 characters of a file in a distant relative path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reply to my own question:

After reading [Chad Birch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41665/chad-birch) above and googling for setting-tabline I found the [TabLineSet](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1507) plugin that does the trick, and some of script explanations [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/67176?threaded=1&var=1&p=2)

Comment: Could you add some examples. The documentation is insufficient.

Comment: install the TabLineSert plugin and in your .vimrc file set the variables you want as follows: "let g:TabLineSet_max_tab_len = 20" for a full list of TabLineSet_ vars look at TabLineSet.vim

Answer (score 8):

You can do this pretty nicely for gvim with the setting 'guitablabel'.

Here's an excerpt from my .gvimrc, which modifies the default to only show up to 12 characters of the filename, but keeps the '+' for modified buffers. The tooltip is left unmodified, so you can get the full path from that or by pressing Ctrl-G in command mode.

```
if version >= 700
    "set showtabline to show when more than one tab
    set showtabline=1
    "set tab labels to show at most 12 characters
    set guitablabel=%-0.12t%M
endif

" don't show the toolbar in the GUI (only the menu)
set guioptions-=T

" don't show tear-off menus
set guioptions-=t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:help setting-tabline
```

Seems to have the relevant information, but I'm not familiar enough with vim scripting to be able to help you get the exact effect you want. Hopefully someone else can pick up from this point.

Also see:

```
:help statusline
```

For some info about printing various information, that should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

An example for you to dynamically adjust tab label length based on total tab label length. (this is for vim in console version). Put this at the end of your .vimrc

```
if exists( '+showtabline' )
    function! MyTabLine()
        let s = ''
        let wn = ''
        let t = tabpagenr()
        let i = 1

        let cnt = 0
        let totalLen = 0
        while i <= tabpagenr( '$' )
          let winnr = tabpagewinnr( i )
          let buflist = tabpagebuflist( i )
          let bufnr = buflist[winnr - 1]
          let file = bufname( bufnr )
          let buftype = getbufvar( bufnr , 'buftype' )
          if buftype == 'nofile'
              if file =~ '\/.'
                  let file = substitute( file , '.*\/\ze.' , '' , '' )
              endif
          else
              let file = fnamemodify( file , ':p:t' )
          endif
        "<Number><Space><file><Space>
          let totalLen = totalLen + 3 + len(file)
          let i = i + 1
        endwhile

        let i = 1 
        while i <= tabpagenr( '$' )
            let buflist = tabpagebuflist( i )
            let winnr = tabpagewinnr( i )
            let s .= '%' . i . 'T'
            let s .= ( i == t ? '%1*' : '%2*' )
            let wn = tabpagewinnr( i ,'$' )

            let s .= '%#TabNum#'
            let s .= i
            "let s .= '%*'
            let s .= ( i == t ? '%#TabLineSel#' : '%#TabLine#' )
            let bufnr = buflist[winnr - 1]
            let file = bufname( bufnr )
            let buftype = getbufvar( bufnr , 'buftype' )
            if buftype == 'nofile'
                if file =~ '\/.'
                    let file = substitute( file , '.*\/\ze.' , '' , '' )
                endif
            else
                let file = fnamemodify( file , ':p:t' )
            endif

            "echo totalLen . "/" . &columns . ", file=" . file
            if totalLen > &columns && len(file) > 16
                let file = strpart( file, 0, 6 )  . "~" . strpart( file, len(file)-10 )
            endif
            if file == ''
                let file = '[No Name]'
            endif
            let s .= ' ' . file . ' '
            let i = i + 1
        endwhile
        let s .= '%T%#TabLineFill#%='
        let s .= ( tabpagenr('$') > 1 ? '%999XX' : 'X' )
        return s
    endfunction
    set stal=2
    set tabline=%!MyTabLine()
    highlight link TabNum Special
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [blog post](http://blog.golden-ratio.net/2008/08/19/using-tabs-in-vim/) was the most concise of all.

The link provides the following function which should be placed in your `.gvimrc` file.

```
function! GuiTabLabel()
    " add the tab number
    let label = '['.tabpagenr()

    " modified since the last save?
    let buflist = tabpagebuflist(v:lnum)
    for bufnr in buflist
        if getbufvar(bufnr, '&modified')
            let label .= '*'
            break
        endif
    endfor

    " count number of open windows in the tab
    let wincount = tabpagewinnr(v:lnum, '$')
    if wincount > 1
        let label .= ', '.wincount
    endif
    let label .= '] '

    " add the file name without path information
    let n = bufname(buflist[tabpagewinnr(v:lnum) - 1])
    let label .= fnamemodify(n, ':t')

    return label
endfunction

set guitablabel=%{GuiTabLabel()}
```

Comment: link to blog is broken

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tabline plugin, [mintabline.vim](https://github.com/Sangdol/mintabline.vim/), that lets you configure the maximum length of tab names.

It's as easy as putting this in your vimrc:

```
Plug 'sangdol/mintabline.vim'
let g:mintabline_tab_max_chars = 15
```